# Sync Licensing for released music

Tags: voice

I have songs out that I would like to submit to sync libraries. I'm curious if it is possible with the song already on streaming platforms.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because business and legal questions are explicitly off topic as per the [help center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)